# How to wrap dynamic input and label in div class in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm rendering `input` fields and `labels` dynamically however I'm trying to wrap the elements in `<div class="col-sm-12"`. Couldn't find a better way of doing it as I'm appending `input` and `label` separately.

```
var chk = $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', id: inputName, name: inputName }).appendTo(checkBox);
var chkLabel = $('<label />', { 'for': inputName, text: inputName, id: inputName, name: inputName }).appendTo(checkBox);
```

The above renders as

```
<input type="text">
<label>text</label>
```

I tried something like, but pretty sure this is wrong. Can someone point out a proper way how to wrap these elements in `div`

```
$('div.className').append('<div class="col-sm-12>'+ chk + chkLabel + '</div>')
```

End result should be

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
 <input type="text">
 <label>text</label>
</div>
```

**Solution**

```
 $(chkBoxElement).each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.add(checkBoxLabel).wrapAll('<div class="col-sm-12"/>');
})
```

Comment: Why don't you create the `div` first, then append the `input` and `label` elements to the `div`?

Comment: then it will append all `input` and `label` in that div similar to what it's already doing. They need to be in separate `col-sm-12`

Comment: Found my answer now!